# Primefaces Two Websockets on one Page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, websocket, push, atmosphere

I am devloping an Application which is very Data-Driven. Therefore I like to get my View updated from the Database-Changes.
Now I try to open two Sockets with PrimeFacesPush but only one socket gets the event.

Here a small snippet for you.

```
<h2>Pushtest</h2>
<h:outputLabel id="output1" value="#{someDataBean.data}"/><br/>
<h:outputLabel id="output2" value="#{otherDataBean.data}"/><br/>


<p:socket channel="/someData"  >
   <p:ajax event="message" update=":output1"/>
</p:socket>             
<p:socket channel="/otherData"  >
    <p:ajax event="message" update=":output2"/>
</p:socket>
```

The outputlabels receive their data from different Data-tables. Therefore I need two parallel open websockets. The Websockets are open but the second can't recieve the Event. Can anyone tell me how get thing working?